# Unserialising a collection of elements in XML into a List<T>

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp and trying to deserialise a collection of nodes into a property in a class:

```
client.Execute<Foo>(req);
```

where

```
public class Foo 
{
    public List<Bar> Bar{get;set;}
    ...
}
public class Bar
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and the xml response is:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar><Id>4</Id><Name>asdf4</Name></Bar>
    <Bar><Id>5</Id><Name>asdf5</Name></Bar>
    <Bar><Id>6</Id><Name>asdf6</Name></Bar>
</Foo>
```

But, always the property has one Bar element with all fields set to null. I've researched and all the answers suggested using as few classes as necessary. Here that isn't possible. What do I have to do to get this response formatted into a list? I've also tried specifying the xml deserializer explicitly to the DotNet deserializer as per a question from a few years ago to no joy.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `List<Bar>` that you want, you just need to change your `Execute<T>` to:

```
client.Execute<List<Bar>>(req);
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, `Foo` has other properties. So your class may look something like this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public List<Bar> Bar {get;set;}
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I think you may need to change your xml, if at all possible, to be more like this:

```
<Foo>
    <Bars>
        <Bar><Id>4</Id><Name>asdf4</Name></Bar>
        <Bar><Id>5</Id><Name>asdf5</Name></Bar>
        <Bar><Id>6</Id><Name>asdf6</Name></Bar>
    </Bars>
    <OtherProp>this</OtherProp>
</Foo>
```

And then change your `Foo` to:

```
public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
```

If you are able to alter your xml structure, and change that class, your `client.Execute<Foo>(req);` should give you what you want.

Comment: that isn't possible because `Foo` has other properties.